# How to read file and group by the lines into a new file based on key using Java

Tags: java, group-by

I am new to Java and have to implement below logic.
I have to read entire file (Approx. 50 MB)and and write a new file based on group by on invoiceNum(key) present in the file.

For example -

My file content is

```
DETAIL|8834|2020-02-14|31|1964|abc|acb||SG|SG|802|||||||1200.0000|8147DBD670B74E65A848|3584453|abc
DETAIL|8834|2020-02-14|32|1964|abc|abc||SG|SG|802|||||||1200.0000|8147DBD670B74E65A848|3584453|abc
DETAIL|8834|2020-02-14|33|1964|abc|abc||SG|SG|802|||||||1200.0000|8147DBD670B74E65A848|3584453|abc
DETAIL|8834|2020-02-14|34|1964|abc|abc||SG|SG|802|||||||1200.0000|8147DBD670B74E65A848|3584453|abc
DETAIL|8834|2020-02-14|35|1964|abc|abc||SG|SG|802|||||||1200.0000|8147DBD670B74E65A848|3584453|abc
DETAIL|8834|2020-02-14|36|1964|abc|abc||SG|SG|802|||||||1232.3700|8147DBD670B74E65A848|3584453|abc
DETAIL|8834|2020-02-14|34|1964|abc|abc||SG|SG|802|||||||1200.0000|8147DBD670B74E65A848|3584455|abc
DETAIL|8834|2020-02-14|35|1964|abc|abc||SG|SG|802|||||||1200.0000|8147DBD670B74E65A848|3584455|abc
DETAIL|8834|2020-02-14|36|1964|abc|abc||SG|SG|802|||||||1232.3700|8147DBD670B74E65A848|3584455|abc
```

In this file content I have 2 invoice number (3584453 and 3584455)
So 1st 5 lines belongs to invoice number - 3584453  and all 5 lines should be copied to new file say test1.txt and remaining 2 lines belongs to invoice number - 3584455 and these 2 lines should be copied to new file say test2.txt

I will have around 15k lines in file and I should create new file for all unique invoice numbers. I am using jdk 7.

Could anyone please help with this logic?

Thank you.

Comment: Will the lines for an invoice always be together? --- What have you tried so far, or are you just hoping we'll write your code for you? --- *FYI:* There are 9 lines in total, 6 for the first invoice and 3 for the second invoice. Not 5 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution (that is not very efficient though) is to load the content of the entire file in memory e.g. using `Files.readAllLines(Path, Charset)` and then group the data into a `Map<String, List<String>` which represents the mapping from invoice ID to lines that belong to this invoice ID:

```
Map<String, List<String>> groupedData = new HashMap<>();
for (String line: lines) {
    String[] split = line.split("\\|");
    String invoiceId = split[<index_of_id>]
    List<String> groupedLines = groupedData.computeIfAbsent(invoiceId, (key) -> new ArrayList<>());
    groupedLines.add(line);
 }
```

You can then iterate over all the entries in the map and save it to individual files (again have a look a the [Files API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html)).

There are better solutions that involve e.g. Streams so that the entire content of the file is not stored in memory at once, but the Files API should give you a good starting point and maybe the solution is even efficient enough for your use case.

Comment: The String.split method uses a regular expression and not a plain String to do the spitting. Regular expression of "|" will create an array of a single character per index. You should escape the | by adding \ in front. See my answer: line.split("\\|");

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all lines of an invoice are together, you simply "break" on invoice number change to switch to a new file.

The logic will be like this:

- For each line from input file:

  - If invoice number is different from previous:

    - If not first invoice number: Close (old) output file.
    - Open new output file.
  - Write line to output file.
- Close (last) output file.

Answer (score 0):

You can start of dividing the process into smaller tasks. E.g.

1. Reading the input file one by one and identify the order number.
2. Opening and writing lines into a file.
3. Closing the file.

The following example uses a Class 'FileUtils' that will take care of the output file operations.

```
public class FileUtils{
private static int indx = 1;
private File file;
private BufferedWriter out;

public FileUtils(){
    String filename = "test"+indx+".txt";
    file = new File(filename);
    try {
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(file, true);
        out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    indx++;
}

public void write(String str){
    try {
        out.write(str);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void close(){
    if(out != null) {
        try {
            System.out.println("File stored at " + file.getAbsolutePath());
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

}

The constructor will create a new file based on an incremental index (indx). Then the BufferedWriter out will be created and available as an object variable.

The write method just uses the BufferedWriter already created to write the String into the file.

Finally, the close method closes the file.

In order to use this FileUtils in the whole process, you need to read the input file, identify the order number in the line (using pipe delimeter), create a new BufferedWriter (FileUtils) for each different order and keep a reference of that FileUtils in a Map so you can reuse it while scanning the input file.
For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
    File inputFile = new File("C:\\tmp\\orders.txt");
    BufferedReader reader;
    Map<String, FileUtils> fileM = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            String [] lineTkns = line.split("\\|");
            String order = lineTkns[19];
            FileUtils fu = fileM.get(order);
            if (fu == null){
                fu = new FileUtils();
                fileM.put(order, fu);
            }
            fu.write(line+"\n");
            //read next line
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (Map.Entry<String,FileUtils> entry : fileM.entrySet())
        entry.getValue().close();
}
```

The above code fragment starts by opening the input file 'C:\tmp\orders.txt' and read it line by line. The line is split by '|' and the order number is identified at the 20th place. If the fileM Map does not already have a key by that order number, a new FileUtils is created. Else the already created FileUtils (containing the BufferWriter) is used.
When all the lines are scanned and written, the fileM is iterated and each instance of the map value is closed.

The above code creates two files, test1.txt and test2.txt with the following output:
test1.txt

> DETAIL|8834|2020-02-14|31|1964|abc|acb||SG|SG|802|||||||1200.0000|8147DBD670B74E65A848|3584453|abc
> DETAIL|8834|2020-02-14|32|1964|abc|abc||SG|SG|802|||||||1200.0000|8147DBD670B74E65A848|3584453|abc
> DETAIL|8834|2020-02-14|33|1964|abc|abc||SG|SG|802|||||||1200.0000|8147DBD670B74E65A848|3584453|abc
> DETAIL|8834|2020-02-14|34|1964|abc|abc||SG|SG|802|||||||1200.0000|8147DBD670B74E65A848|3584453|abc
> DETAIL|8834|2020-02-14|35|1964|abc|abc||SG|SG|802|||||||1200.0000|8147DBD670B74E65A848|3584453|abc
> DETAIL|8834|2020-02-14|36|1964|abc|abc||SG|SG|802|||||||1232.3700|8147DBD670B74E65A848|3584453|abc

and test2.txt

> DETAIL|8834|2020-02-14|34|1964|abc|abc||SG|SG|802|||||||1200.0000|8147DBD670B74E65A848|3584455|abc
> DETAIL|8834|2020-02-14|35|1964|abc|abc||SG|SG|802|||||||1200.0000|8147DBD670B74E65A848|3584455|abc
> DETAIL|8834|2020-02-14|36|1964|abc|abc||SG|SG|802|||||||1232.3700|8147DBD670B74E65A848|3584455|abc